# Populate Postgresql Table without String Queries

Tags: python, postgresql, datatable, populate

I want to populate a PostgreSQL table with python. I can only see 'psycopg2' where string queries are executed. Is there any way to do it without converting the queries to a string? For Example - I have a class called Country and it has attributes like population, area, the capital. Now I want to populate the country table with each instance of country.
I want to do it without using any framework. Any kind of assistance will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A `SQL` database will only respond to a SQL query as  a string. So either you provide that string yourself or use/build a framework that does it for you. Personally building the query yourself is clearer and better over the long run. To make it easier to do this dynamically in `psycopg2` I would suggest this [Sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).

Comment: Bottom line, if you use an SQL database you need to learn SQL.